# How to show results of a PHP file, into the current page after form input?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to webpage design/coding so my understanding is somewhat limited. I'm trying to implement a "Search By: " feature to this makeshift events site that I am making, where it orders it by name and date of the events stored in the MySQL database. On the current page, there's a form that has two submit buttons, one for both name and date, as shown below.

```
    <div>
        <form action="resources/files/sport_events.php" method="post">
          <lable>Search By: </lable>
          <button type="submit" name="name" value="name">Name</button>
          <button type="submit" name="date" value="date" >Date</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

followed by a php inlcude() that links it to the *sport_events.php*.

The sports_events.php itself, contains the if/elseif/else stataments that receives the data from the $_POST pass on by the form above and deteminds which query to use based on it, which in turn is passed through a function to the foreach(), where it takes the data, stored in the database, to make the event's "tables" shown at the current page. This is the code for it:

```
<?php
//SQL Queries
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $queryByName = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_category = "Sports" ORDER BY event_name;';
  $result = $queryByName;
} elseif (isset($_POST['date'])) {
  $queryByDate = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_category = "Sports" ORDER BY event_date;';
  $result = $queryByDate;
} else {
  $defaultQuery = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_category = "Sports";';
  $result = $defaultQuery;
}

function executeQuery($query){
  include('dbh.home.php');
  $data = $conn->query($query);
  return $data;
}
//Table of Events code.
foreach(executeQuery($result) as $row) {
  // Changes the date format before it passes through.
  $date_to_sort = strtotime($row['event_date']);
  $sorted_date = date("F j, Y",$date_to_sort);
  ?>
  <div class="eventsTable">
    <div class="eventImage">
      <img src="<?php echo $row['event_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['event_name'] ?> Image" />
    </div>
  <div class="eventsData">
      <ul class="sectionOne">
        <li class="event_title"><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></li>
        <li class="accountUser">
          <img class="thumbsDown" alt="Thumbs Down" src="resources/images/system/thumbs-down_left.png" height="20" width="20" onclick="eventDOWN(<?php echo $row['event_id'] ?>)" />
          <img class="thumbsUp" alt="Thumbs Up" src="resources/images/system/thumbs-up_left.png" height="20" width="20" onclick="eventUP(<?php echo $row['event_id'] ?>)" />
          <button id="book_<?php echo $row['event_id']?>" onclick="location.href='booking.php'">Book In</button>
        </li>
        <li><?php echo $row['event_description']; ?></li>
        <li><span class="label">Date: </span><?php echo $sorted_date; ?></td></li>
        <li class="more" id="more_<?php echo $row['event_id']?>"><button type="button" onclick="revealMoreLess(<?php echo $row['event_id']?>)">see more...</button></li>
      </ul>
      <!--Hidden from view untill click "see more..."-->
      <ul class="sectionTwo" id="sectionTwo_<?php echo $row['event_id']?>">
        <li><span class="label">Location: </span><?php echo $row['event_venue']; ?></li>
        <li><span class="label">Organiser: </span><?php echo $row['event_organiser']; ?></li>
        <li><span class="label">Contact: </span><a href="<?php echo $row['contact_info']; ?>"><?php echo $row['contact_info']; ?></a></li>
        <li><button type="button" onClick="revealMoreLess(<?php echo $row['event_id']?>)">see less...</button> </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <?php
    }


// Checks if the current User is logged in to display the "accountUser" only elements or not.
    if($_SESSION['user_id'] === "guest"){ ?>
      <script type="text/JavaScript">
        bookinList = document.getElementsByClassName("accountUser");
        document.getElementsByClassName('accountUser');
        if(bookinList){
          for(var i=0; i<bookinList.length; i++){
            bookinList[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
        }
      </script>
      <?php
    } else {
      ?>
      <script type="text/JavaScript">
        bookinList = document.getElementsByClassName("accountUser");
        document.getElementsByClassName('accountUser');
        if(bookinList){
          for(var i=0; i<bookinList.length; i++){
            bookinList[i].style.visibility = "visible";
          }
        }
      </script>
      <?php
    }
?>
```

When the sports page loads (e.i. current page), everything is displayed as it was intended. However, once I click on any of the submit buttons in the form above, it gets sorted properly, but it's no longer displayed at the current page and instead it loads on the file itself *://localhost/SOMEFOLDER/resources/files/sport_events.php*, in plaintext without any iamges or style elements as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJfga.jpg).

Also, I get the following error message on the same page as the image above, which I didn't use to have before I added the if/elseif/else and function to it. Not sure why is that.

**Notice:** Undefined variable: _SESSION in **C:\xampp\htdocs\SOMEFOLDER\resources\files\sport_events.php** on line **55**

**Notice:** Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\SOMEFOLDER\resources\files\sport_events.php** on line **55**

As you can imagin, my intention was for the events to display those "tables", by a certain order depedning on whether something was selected(by submition) or not(which would just display the default), on the current page.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. If I have missed out any relevent details, please let me know and I would gladly post it.

Comment: You cannot use sessions without starting the session first session_start(); unless you enabled auto start with htacess or php ini

Comment: @KevinGales the session has been started already on another page passed on to this one by the include(). In fact, I tested it out before and sport_events.php complained that the session has already started and that there's no need to do so again.